# oracle sql statement automatic transform / rewrite

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, url-rewriting

We have a reference data DB that is like an ODS/MDM but it's read only.  The data is updated from the authoritative systems on various schedules.  Every table maintains historic data - updates do an update existing & insert new, deletes do an update existing.

All tables are of the following form:

```
table <name> 
   surrogate key,
   business key(s),
   attribute(s),
   effective_start_date,
   effective_end_date
```

I want to expose 2 sets of views to users/systems for querying.
First view set is views that return only the current records from the respective table.  That's easy.
Second view set should provide a way to query (by joining) multiple tables (all with history) and get the effective history of the result set.

For example, if a user issues something like the following query:

```
select
   A.busines_key,
   B.business_key,
   effective_start_date(),
   effective_end_date()
from
   A inner join B on (A.b_fk_col = B.business_key)
```

then I need to transform this statement into:

```
select
   A.busines_key,
   B.business_key,
   max( A.effective_start_date, B.effective_start_date ) effect_start_date,
   min( A.effective_end_date, B.effective_end_date ) effective_end_date
from
   A inner join B on (A.b_fk_col = B.business_key)
where
   (A.effective_start_date between B.effective_start_date and B.effective_end_date
   or
   A.effective_end_date between B.effective_start_date and B.effective_end_date)
```

Really, what I need to be able to do is to add a step to the query plan right after the join(s):
e.g.

Instead of the original:

```
SELECT STATEMENT      
  MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN
    BUFFER SORT        
      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ID      A
        INDEX FULL SCAN             A_B_FK_IDX
    BUFFER SORT
      INDEX FULL SCAN               B_PK_IDX
```

I could get something like:

```
SELECT STATEMENT      
  ****  ADDED ****
  EFFECTIVE RANGES                     // create/modify where & select clauses
    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ID        A  // get the eff dates from A
    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ID        B  // get the eff dates from B
  ****************                     
    MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN
      BUFFER SORT        
        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ID        A
          INDEX FULL SCAN               A_B_FK_IDX
      BUFFER SORT
        INDEX FULL SCAN             B_PK_IDX
```

Any thoughts on how I could do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Is there a performance issue you are trying to correct?

Comment: You seem to be describing partitioning.  Start here:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm.

Comment: It's not a performance issue.  It's about ensuring the data integrity of queries against historical data.

Comment: For example, if table A has records for a business key 'x'

Comment: You need a dynamic SQL and/or ref cursor.